# Unit testing angular and jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

How does one go about unit testing in angular something in the index.html file?

For example:  I want to create a unit test that checks that the body tag has a specific class assigned to it.  Is this possible

Most unit test or spec files are made for components but I cant seem to access the body tag.

this is a working css unit test for anything inside a component, just no idea how to get access to the body tag of the index.html page.

```
  it('should have class-name in body class tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement;

    expect(compiled.query(By.css('.class-name'))).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access body element via `document`, then inspect that the elements `className` attribute has the expected class name.

Here is a [stackblitz showing a functional example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-4shbbf).

```
describe("Integration::AppComponent", () => {
  let component;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent        
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should set a class on the body element", () => {
    const body = document.body;
    expect(body.className).toContain('my-class');
  });
});
```

Here is how my little example component sets the body style.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  ngOnInit(){
    document.body.className += ' my-class';
  }
}
```

A word of caution - if you're using something like Angular Universal, `document` won't be available when your component is run on the server.

Comment: I tried that, it seems that the body is not available 
https://codeshare.io/GkL4bL
https://imgur.com/laIbIQy

Comment: My prior answer was incorrect. I've updated it with what I think is an answer and a working example that should work for you.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the assistance.  I tried the stackblitz example as when I put this code in my local it was not working.  But I am at a loss I do not see the code in the functional example over at stackblitz.  Any idea why?

Comment: The error I am getting on my local is this
Chrome 81.0.4044 (Windows 10.0.0) Integration::AppComponent should set a class on the body element FAILED
        Error: Expected '' to contain 'mat-app-background'.

Comment: When I debug I get body.className = '' so it seems that its not getting it even though they index.html has <body class="class-name"> in it.

Comment: Stackblitz should be working. How are you setting the `body` style? Can you edit your post to include the component being tested?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PK6lVuV <-- index.html file
https://imgur.com/a/5huFr67 <-- app.component.spec.ts
https://imgur.com/a/1NQnqeA <-- error

Comment: Should note that I see the stackblitz working now :) which is good but I noticed that the body tag is in the ngOnInit I am trying to add it direct in the HTML of the index.html
Which I changed and I see works, will study what you have and see what I can figure out.  any assistance is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're setting it directly in the index.html file, you will not be able to test it with the typical karma/jasmine setup. This is because your tests do not run with index.html and instead run in their own instance. It sounds like you're not testing a specific component, but rather testing the whole app. I would look into E2E testing using Protractor or Cypress.

Comment: Hey Spots, thank you for the response. I would say I agree 100% except that your stackblitz shows it working, even when I add the body tag to the index.html? Is there a reason why the stackblitz would work and it not work local?